# How to test a mediation model in panel data?

Tags: stata, panel-data, mediation

I have a research design with a mediation effect between 3 variables over a period of 5 years (panel data). And I would appreciate it if you can provide advice for analysis.

**the independent variable** = CEO 
which include the eduation(level of education: PHD, MSC, etc), workexperience info (work exp in years & functions),  & demographic details ( gender, age)

**Dependent variable** = FIRM performance (market value, sales, net income)

**Mediation variable** = diversity of partners (total amount of partners a company has, in which industry'multiple' and which function'multiple').

**Panel Data**
Have collected all data over a 5-year period. (changes in all 3 variables)
I have used 0,1 to for CEO work experience, function and industry
I have used 0,1 for partners as well, both for the industries and functions.

After consulting with some people I was suggested to use STATA to analyse the paneldata & relationships over the 5 year period.

Can you please provide suggestions for the analysis.

Thank you very much.
C.A.

Comment: Your mediational model implies that you are claiming that the CEO's education level causes the diversity of partners. Did you intend this?

Comment: Yes, that the CEO's education and prior work experience in various fields causes diversity of partners.